# update hook to delete and bulk update pathauto aliases

Tags: features, updating, path-aliases

I have put all of my SEO settings into a feature, in order to migrate the settings from a dev site to a live site. Is there a way to write an update hook that will delete all of my existing content aliases and then bulk update them automatically?

Comment: There is already settings in admin section of pathauto module.

Comment: I know. The goal is to run those commands through an update hook and not through the ui.

Comment: Sorry, I never checked for update hook. If I found, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I do it with the following method:

```
function MYMODULE_update_7100(&$sandbox) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');
  module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto.pathauto');

  // Delete the existing node aliases.
  db_delete('url_alias')
    ->condition('source', 'node/%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();

  // Regenerate the node aliases.
  $nids = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node}")->fetchCol();
  pathauto_node_update_alias_multiple($nids, 'bulkupdate');

  // Delete the topics taxonomy aliases.
  db_delete('url_alias')
    ->condition('source', 'taxonomy/term/%', 'LIKE')
    ->execute();

  // Regenerate the taxonomy aliases.
  $tids = db_query("SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_term_data}")->fetchCol();
  pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_alias_multiple($tids, 'bulkupdate');
}
```